# Can there be two inequalities?

Tags: inequality

$$x+a+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}>b$$

I can consider this inequality for $a,b,x>0$.

1) $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}>b-(x+a)$

$$x^2+a^2>b^2-2b(x+a)+(x+a)^2$$
$$0>b^2-2b(x+a)+2ax$$
$$x(2b-2a)>b^2-2ba$$
$$x>\frac{b^2-2ba}{(2b-2a)}$$

2)  $(x+a)-b>-\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$

$$x^2+a^2<b^2-2b(x+a)+(x+a)^2$$
$$0<b^2-2b(x+a)+2ax$$
$$x(2b-2a)<b^2-2ba$$
$$x<\frac{b^2-2ba}{(2b-2a)}$$

I get two inequalities. What is Im doing wrong?

Comment: You can't just square the second one, because one side is negative. For example, you could have "$2\gt -3$", but when you square both sides the left hand side is $4$ and the right hand side is $9$; on the other hand, if you had $2\gt -1$, when you square the left hand side is $4$ but the right hand side is $1$. So you do not know the relationship between $((x+a)-b)^2$ and $x^2+a^2$ in the second case.

Comment: Two sources of mistake. 1. Remember that when multiplying an inequality by a negative number, you should 'invert the inequality'. 2. Be careful when squaring unknown quantities. Notice that $1 > -3$, but $1< 9$. However, *if you know that $d>0$* then $c>d$ actually implies $c^2 > d^2$.

Comment: 2) is particularly egregious.  If $(x+a) - b\ge 0 \ge -\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ we have no idea of their relative magnitudes and can conclude *nothing* about their squares.  And if $0 > (x+a) -b > -\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ then the exact opposite is true and $x^2 +a^2 > [(x+a)-b]^2$.  But 1) is wrong too.

Answer (score 3):

You should use this fundamental fact about irrational inequalities:

> On its domain, $\;\sqrt{A}>B\iff A>B^2\: \textbf{ or }\: B<0.$

Answer (score 2):

You can't multiply or divide and keep the inequalities the the same unless you know the term you are multiplying by is positive.

In 1) $\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} > b-(x+a)$ does not mean

$(\sqrt{x^2 + a^2})^2 > [b-(x+a)]^2$ unless  $\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} > |b-(x+a)|$ and you don't know that.

And $x(2b-2a)>b^2-2ba$ does not mean

$x > \frac {b^2 - 2ba}{2b-2a}$ unless you know that $2b - 2a > 0$.  And you do not know that.

And $(x+a)-b>-\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ most certainly does *NOT* mean

$[(x+a)-b]^2 > (-\sqrt{x^2+a^2})^2$.  That $-\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}$ is negative should have been a big tip off that if $(x+a) - b$ is positive we'd know absolutely nothing how the values compare and if $(x+a)-b < 0$ then this statement is completely false so $0 > (x+a)-b > -\sqrt{x^2 +a^2}\implies \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} > |(x+a)-b|\implies x^2 + a^2 > [(x+a)-b]^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I am going to deal with the case in which $b - x - a \geq 0$. Otherwise, any value of $x$ that satisfies $x \geq b - a$ is a solution.

\begin{align*}
& x + a + \sqrt{x^{2} + a^{2}} > b \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{x^{2} + a^{2}} > b - x - a \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2} + a^{2} > (b - x - a)^{2}\\\\
b - x - a \geq 0
\end{cases}\\\\
& \begin{cases}
x^{2} + a^{2} > b^{2} + x^{2} + a^{2} - 2bx - 2ab + 2ax\\\\
b - x - a \geq 0
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
b^{2} - 2bx - 2ab + 2ax < 0\\\\
b - x - a \geq 0
\end{cases}\\\\
& \begin{cases}
b^{2} + 2x(a - b) - 2ab < 0\\\\
b - x - a \geq 0
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
2x(a-b) < 2ab - b^{2}\\\\
b - x - a \geq0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then you consider the three possible situations: $a > b$, $a = b$ or $a < b$.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you want to solve for $x$ in $$\sqrt{x^2+a^2}>b-a-x,$$ note that since LHS is never negative, the inequality is automatically true whenever RHS is negative, that is, for all $b-a<x.$  Thus, suppose $b-a-x\ge 0,$ then you may square both sides to have $$x^2+a^2>(b-a-x)^2=b^2-2b(a+x)+(a+x)^2=b^2-2ab-2bx+a^2+2ax+x^2,$$ which simplifies to $$0>b^2-2ab-2bx+2ax=b^2-2ab-(2b-2a)x,$$ or $$(2b-2a)x>b^2-2ab=b(b-2a).$$ Now recall that we assumed that $b-a\ge x.$ Again we have three subsidiary cases, namely $a=b,a<b,a>b.$ You can check that in the first case we have no solutions. If we have $a<b,$ then we can divide both sides by $2b-2a$ without changing the order, to get $$x>\frac{b(b-2a)}{2(b-a)}.$$ In the final case this inequality is reversed.